# T-SQL - How to split a string base on a list of position in a temp table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let say I have this T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @data nvarchar(1000) = 'AAAAA,BBBBB;CCCCC#DDDDD!EEEEE';

SELECT pos FROM #TEMP; --value in the #TEMP for example => 6, 12
```

I would like to split the `@data` at position in the `#temp` table

I'm expecting the output to be:

```
AAAAA
BBBBB
CCCCC#DDDDD!EEEEE
```

Can anyone help me with this in T-SQL? Thanks in advance

Comment: It's extremely poor practice to store delimited data in a single field. This cries out for an additional table, at which point this is suddenly a trivial problem.

Comment: Tables without a clustered index do not have a defined order. Unless your substrings are always increasing in length, you're going to need another column in your temp table to order them by.

Answer (score 0):

I think something like the following will give you the result you want.

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@data, LAG(pos+1, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY (pos)), pos - LAG(pos+1, 1,0) OVER (ORDER BY (pos)))
FROM #temp
UNION ALL
SELECT SUBSTRING(@data, (SELECT MAX(pos)+1 FROM #temp), len(@data))
```

The first part of the `UNION ALL` gets the substrings for each row of your `#temp` table (using `LAG` to look at the previous row as well). So, in your example, 0-6 and 7-12 (7 instead of 6 since you are eliminating the character at the splitting point).

The second part of the `UNION ALL` gets the remainder of the string from `MAX(pos)+1` to the end. (Again, `MAX(pos)+1` instead of just `MAX(pos)` to eliminate the character at the splitting point.)